# Please remove the installation medium then press enter

Tags: system-installation

I'm installing Ubuntu 17.04. After the system installation is complete, I get this prompt:

> Please remove the installation medium, then press Enter.

What should I do?

Comment: The disc is no longer needed at this point.  Remove it and reboot the computer.

Comment: What should you do? Isn't it saying what you needed to do? If you're using a USB, just press Enter and remove USB after it finishing reboot

Comment: Please try this:
In the menu at the top of the screen, select:
Devices-> Optical Drives -> Remove disk from virtual drive -> force unmount.

Answer (score 10):

The installation is asking you to remove whatever media (e.g. *USB drive, CD, DVD, etc*) that you used to boot the installer and then press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to reboot the machine.

This way it won't boot into the installer again.

Comment: Alternately, if you don't want to do that for some reason, maybe you don't have a handy place to store the CD at the moment for example, you can either: -- just open the tray if it is a CD or DVD, or -- go ahead and press enter, but catch the boot in the early phase to direct the machine back to booting from the hard drive you installed Ubuntu on. In some cases you get a menu ANYWAY. In others you have to enter the bios settings.

Comment: When you look at Devices > Optical Drives "Remove disk from virtual drive" is disabled. Click on the ISO, get it checked and then you can click "Remove disk from virtual drive".

Answer (score 9):

If you have a virtual disk, this is the screen on which you click machine in the top left hand corner and then click storage.  Then you have to choose the second option underneath storage devices, go to the right and look under attributes and uncheck the box that says 'Live CD/DVD'.  I hope this helps!