# I've been trying to install Ubuntu for about 4 times now and every time it gets stuck at the last stage, i.e, at the restart point

Tags: dual-boot, hp

I've been trying to install Ubuntu for about 4 times now and  every time it gets stuck at the last stage, i.e, at the restart point. It gets stuck there and when I power down and try rebooting, I do get a grab screen and when I select Ubuntu its stuck again.

Comment: Did you verify your install media before you actually installed?  What release of Ubuntu are you talking about?  (desktop/server, release etc)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/915814/please-remove-the-installation-medium-then-press-enter?rq=1

Comment: Yes. I tried once by selecting the hard drive and rest of three times I triend installing it in SSD although i thought it was a mistake until i found that it behaves the same way when tried installing it in Hard drive. Also it is ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.